# Buttons not working on mobile phone but work on every browser on pc (chrome,safari,firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I have these buttons that redirect to the stripe checkout page. They work on every browser on pc but not on mobile. When I check the responsive part on pc everything works fine.

The code is simple

```js
document.querySelector(".checkout").addEventListener("click", function () {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    lineItems: [
      {
        price: "api key is present on website",
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "subscription",
    successUrl: "url is present on website",
    cancelUrl: "url is present on website",
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn checkout">Get Started</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try add return at the function

```js
document.querySelector('.checkout').addEventListener("click", function(){
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            lineItems: [
                {
                    price: "api key is present on website",
                    quantity: 1,
                },
            ],
            mode: "subscription",
            successUrl: "url is present on website",
            cancelUrl: "url is present on website"
        })
    
    })
```

Comment: Thank you but not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).